# "Woken up by" or "woken by"?

Tags: difference, verbs, phrasal-verbs

Which one is more grammatically correct?

> He was woken up by his alarm clock.
>
> He was woken by his alarm clock.

Comment: Apparently this is a personal (or perhaps regional) thing, but I'd lean toward "awakened by".

Comment: @Hellion: That's very interesting! My first thought was *awakened* sounds rather "dated" to me. But have a look at US/UK differences in [this chart](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=was+woken+by%2Cwas+woken+up+by%2Cwas+awakened+by&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=). It seems pretty clear that although BrE is adopting OP's versions faster than AmE, your version is still the dominant one on both sides of the pond.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In OP's context, *up* makes no difference to the meaning, and [isn't included in most usages...](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=was%20woken%20by,was%20woken%20up%20by&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)

[image]

...but as the chart implies, there's nothing particularly "unusual" about including it, either.

But in contexts where the "base" verb *to wake* actually *ends a clause*, we're much more likely to include the preposition. It's not easy for me to show this by charts or corpus searches, but if you look at...

> [When will he wake [up]?](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22when%20will%20he%20wake%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

...it seems clear to me **up** is present more often than not when there's no additional text in the utterance.

There's no actual "rule" in play here - but idiomatically, native speakers have a tendency to discard **up** *when there's another preposition following the full phrasal verb form **to wake up***.